# How to execute from Makefile? (C++)

Tags: c++, makefile

is it possible to excute from the makefile?

My make file is like this

```
tp2: main.o complexe.o
    g++ main.o complexe.o -o tp2 
    
    
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp 

echangiste.o: complexe.cpp complexe.h
    g++ -c complexe.cpp
    

clean:
    rm *.o tp2
```

I want to execute tp2 when it's created directly from the makefile. I tried repla

```
g++ main.o complexe.o -o tp2 && ./tp2
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I don't see where an executable is finally created in that makefile, if there would be one, you could also execute it after it was build.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ? Both are online and written in English

Comment: Please explain why making a rule to execute if present and have it depend on "build if not present" is not the solution.

Comment: While there are some valid reasons for doing so, you should be asking yourself why you want to execute from make..   Make is for building things, not running them.   A better solution is to do `make tp2 && ./tp2` from the command line (you could even create a bash script or alias if you want to reduce typing...).

Comment: Alright thanks. I added all: run; run: ./tp2  on my make file and it works once it's built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you tried something like...

```
tp2: main.o complexe.o
        g++ main.o complexe.o -o tp2 && ./tp2
```

then that *should* work, but only if that rule is run and `tp2` was built successfully.  If `make` decides that `tp2` is already up to date then the rule will not be run and `tp2` won't be executed.

The easiest solution would be to simply add an extra rule before the rule for `tp2`...

```
.PHONY: run-tp2
run-tp2: tp2
        ./tp2
```

That assumes you want `run-tp2` to be the default target.

Comment: `touch run-tp2`. There is this thing called [phony targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)… ;)

Comment: @spectras Thanks.  Knew I'd forgotten something :-)